# jQuery - Sidebar popout

Tags: jquery

I have the following:-

**HTML:**

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div id="events-sidebar">
  <div class="inner">
    <h3>TAB NAME</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="events-content">
    <div class="events-container">
      <div id="events-info">
        <h1>THE TITLE</h1>
        <h2>THE SUBTITLE</h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, choro honestatis definitiones ei eum, sit ut erat consul appellantur, usu te illum dissentiunt. Cu viris intellegat efficiendi sit, quo odio partem et
        <span class="arrow-left"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#events-sidebar {
  background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/menu-left.png);
  height: 440px;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: -70px;
  top: 25%;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

#events-sidebar .inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

#events-sidebar h3 {
  color: @pink;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 22px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

#events-content {
  background: #ececec;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 419px;
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: -800px;
}

.events-container {
  border: solid 3px #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 90px;
  position: relative;
  top: 46px;
}

.events-container h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: @pink;
}

.events-container h2 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 44px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: @cyan;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: -22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#events-info {
  padding: 0 22px;
}

.arrow-left {
  background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/arrow-left.png);
  display: block;
  height: 41px;
  width: 46px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -62px;
  top: 152px;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 7;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
// Expand Events Sidebar

$('#events-sidebar').click(function(event){
    if(jQuery('#events-sidebar').hasClass('open')) {
        jQuery('#events-sidebar').animate({
           left: "-=800"
        }, 500);     
        jQuery('.overlay').css({
            display: "none"
        }, 500);
        jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
    } else {
        jQuery('#events-sidebar').animate({
            left: "+=730"
        }, 500);
        jQuery('.overlay').css({
            display: "block"
        }, 500);
        jQuery(this).addClass('open');
    }
});

$('#events-content').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$('.overlay').click(function(event){
        jQuery('#events-sidebar').animate({
           left: "-=800"
        }, 500);     
        jQuery('.overlay').css({
            display: "none"
        }, 500);
        jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

[[SEE JSFIDDLE]](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lp8d6p3/2/)

The issue I am having is that when I click the `.overlay` element to close the `events-sidebar`, the next time I go to open `events-sidebar` the element closes instead of opening, why is this happening and how can I stop this?

The same thing is happening if I add `arrow-left` to the click function as I want to make this clickable to perform the same action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be adding/removing the `open` class to `#events-sidebar`, not `this`, as sometimes `this` will be `#events-siderbar`, but sometimes it will be `.overlay`. So when you click on the overlay to close it, `#events-sidebar` still has the open class.

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lp8d6p3/7/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working code

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lp8d6p3/6/)

```
// Expand Events Sidebar

    $('#events-sidebar, .overlay').click(function(event){
      if($('.overlay').is(':visible')){
            jQuery('#events-sidebar').animate({
               left: "-=730"
            }, 500);     
            jQuery('.overlay').css({
                display: "none"
            }, 500);
            jQuery('#events-sidebar').removeClass('open');
      }else{
        if(jQuery('#events-sidebar').hasClass('open')) {
          jQuery('#events-sidebar').animate({
             left: "-=730"
          }, 500);     
          jQuery('.overlay').css({
              display: "none"
          }, 500);
          jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
        } else {
          jQuery('#events-sidebar').animate({
              left: "+=730"
          }, 500);
          jQuery('.overlay').css({
              display: "block"
          }, 500);
          jQuery(this).addClass('open');
      }
  }

    });

    $('#events-content').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

I've add a condition on where `.overlay` is visible or not to do the right animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#events-sidebar').click(function(event){
        if(jQuery('#events-sidebar').hasClass('open')) {
           jQuery('#events-sidebar').animate({
              left: "<b>-=730</b>"
           }, 500);     
           jQuery('.overlay').css({
               display: "none"
           }, 500);
            jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
        } else {
        jQuery('#events-sidebar').animate({
            left: "+=730"
        }, 500);
        jQuery('.overlay').css({
            display: "block"
        }, 500);
        jQuery(this).addClass('open');
    }
});

$('#events-content').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

`$`('.overlay').click(function(event){
        jQuery('#events-sidebar').animate({
           left: "<b>-=730</b>"
        }, 500);     
        jQuery('.overlay').css({
            display: "none"
        }, 500);
        jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

Comment: When you are opening the box you are adding 730 to left position but when you are closing the box you are decreasing the left position by 800. Because of that the box is going extra 70px inside.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the part of the jQuery which changes the left position by 70px on hover, this is the reason that is there :)